# Blocking IO in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I'm doing some Akka lately and wonder: Can I do blocking I/O in Akka without getting into big trouble? Let us say we have an Actor which does some blocking I/O because it uses a legacy library or for any other reason: Couldn't I just use a special dispatcher for those Actors which a reasonably sized ThreadPool and do blocking I/O without blocking all other actors because they run with a different dispatcher?

What are the downsides of this? And what would be the optimal way to call a 3rd party HTTP-API from an actor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Doing blocking IO is a bad idea in general, and in a reactive multithreaded environment in particular, so your first step is to try to avoid it alltogether, that means looking into using `AsyncHttpClient` or `HttpAsyncClient`.

If that does not work, you can at least mitigate the risks by giving the blocking actors their own threads. This will of course be costly and you still risk filling up their mailboxes, but such is the choice of using blocking IO.

You also might want to look at the IO Actor module for a more raw interface to network IO.

Hope any of this helps,

Cheers,
√

Comment: What about using a Future from within the actor?

Comment: You are still going to block threads, of which you do not have infinite. Actors or futures are not the problem.

Comment: I hate to ask, is there an example for using HTTP calls as a client from an actor, i only could find one which is using a future and waiting for it - which also blocks the thread.

Comment: Just register an completion handler or somesuch, for instance something like this: http://asynchttpclient.github.com/async-http-client/apidocs/com/ning/http/client/AsyncCompletionHandler.html

Comment: But don't you still have an issue of where the async-http-client get's the thread from to execute the callback? I.e. don't you need to provide the library with a thread pool - the one that your akka dispatcher uses probably? Otherwise the library has to create it's own threads right? i.e. i think it's what https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client/pull/7 is getting at.
There's Spray Client https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/spray-client but it's Scala centric.

Comment: @ViktorKlang I agree with Antonty above, the question is can you send messages from that callback function (which may run in a separate thread)?